# Add a set of numbers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sum, addition

I know I can store the numbers in an array first like arr[] = {1,2,3};
then call a sum function to add all the numbers like sum(arr);

But what if I want to not use the arr[] and just call sum(1,2,3)?

The values will be determined by the user so it can be sum(1,2), sum(1,2,3,4,5) or sum(1,2,5)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int addition (int arr[]) {
    int length = log2(*(&arr + 1) - arr);
    int res = 0;
    for (int n=0; n<length + 1; n++){
        res += arr[n];
    }
    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
  int array[] = {5, 10, 15,20};
  int array1[] = {10,15,20,25,30};
    
  addition (array);
  addition (array1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep the code in the question, it's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the function like this:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
auto sum(Ts ...ts)
{
    int arr[]{ ts... };
    addition(arr);
}
```

which stores the variadic arguments into an array, and the calls `addition` on that array.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3Yfdxs).

---

However, you can also simply write `sum` like this:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
auto sum(Ts ...ts)
{
    return (ts + ...);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6KKWEa).

---

Also, if you use a `std::vector` instead of an array, you could write `addition` like this:

```
void addition (std::vector<int> const & v) {
    std::cout << std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0) << "\n";
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jefzah). Note that you can use `accumulate` with an array as well, but the function has to be a template, like this:

```
template<int N>
void addition (int const (&arr)[N]) {
    std::cout << std::accumulate(arr, arr + N, 0) << "\n";
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PbdP5s).

Comment: I'm thinking to use an array to store the numbers in the sum function. Will that work?

Comment: I think so. Why don't you add the `sum` that adds an array to your question?

Comment: I did. The part I'm struggling with is how to store these numbers in an array inside the sum function.

Comment: Ok, then show that code at least. In your question, you say you can do `arr[] = {1,2,3}; sum(arr);`. Show that code.

Comment: With arr[] = {1,2,3}; then calling sum(arr) that works no problem. I tried to make changes on top of this. But it doesn't work and make no sense, I'm kinda lost here.

Comment: int sum (int arr[]) {... }  If the numbers are always the same, I could just do it like sum(int x,int y,int z) but I don't know how to make it possible if the user going to determine the values.

Comment: @David Added an answer.

Comment: I mean I'm trying to figure out how to do it using an array. I know your way is a lot simpler but could you show me how to do with array or ArrayList. And not using template<typename ...Ts>.

Comment: @David Read the answer, I added a version that uses an array.

Comment: Can you do it w/o using the template?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. Implementing a function that takes an arbitrary number of parameters requires a template. Is it the syntax that you don't like? In c++20 you can do [this](https://godbolt.org/z/ofx4ef). It's still a template though.

Comment: Well, it doesn't get much easier than the template solution. But even the code in your question can be greatly simplified with an `<algorithm>`.

Comment: I mean not easier, just wonder is there another approach to solve this problem and sure there are. Not saying your approach with template is bad, it's really good actually and I like it.

Comment: @David Added some more versions.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use stringstreams to handle the process. I imagine the variadic template approach @cigien is going to be more efficient, but stringstreams are really useful for many purposes:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int ssum(std::stringstream &obj) {
    int accumulator = 0;
    std::string buffer;
    while (obj >> buffer) {            //read the stream number by number
        accumulator += stoi(buffer);   //convert to int and add
    }
    return accumulator;
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    std::stringstream os;
    for (auto i : arr) {                  //feed the array into the stream obj
        os << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << ssum(os) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[edit remove string conversion step, just pass stringstream object directly]

Comment: Can you make your ssum(1,2,3,4,5)? Not using the array and use the numbers directly.

Comment: That's probably more of the variadic template approach (compare to, for ex., a python function like ```def adder(*args): return sum(args)```). It's fairly complex in C++ (you have to understand recursive concepts), but here's a good source: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/